# How to collect an image file and save it in database

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

This is a project that collects inputs for name, price and image.

The major problem I am encountering is posting an image from my frontend(html) to the backend(database).

These are my codes, what is the issue

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from datetime import datetime


    class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        price = models.FloatField(default=0)
        image = models.ImageField()
```

forms.py

```
    from django import forms


    class ProductCreationForm(forms.Form):
        name = forms.CharField(label="Product Name", max_length=250, required=True)
        price = forms.DecimalField(label="Price", required=True, initial=0)
        image = forms.ImageField(label="Image", required=True, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': "image/x-png, image/jpeg"}))
```

views.py

```
    def product_create(request):
        form = ProductCreationForm()

        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ProductCreationForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
                price = form.cleaned_data["price"]
                image = form.cleaned_data["image"]

                new_item = Product.objects.create(name=name, price=price, image=image)
                new_item.save()

            return redirect('shelf')


        else:
            return render(request, "workbench/product_create.html", {"form": form})
```

create.html

```
    <form action="", method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" >submit</button>
    </form>
```

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views


    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.shelf, name="shelf"),
        path('/create', views.product_create, name="product-create"),
    ]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Not an error, but the new_item and the image never saves in the database

Answer (score 1):

When accepting files from forms, along with `request.POST`, you should also fetch `request.FILES` as well...

```
form = ProductCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

By the way, the `create(name=name, price=price, image=image)` already saved the item so there's no need to call the `save` method `new_item.save()`.

It would be easier to just work with a `model form` instead. So I'm just updating your code here...

`models.py` file:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_uploads/', null=True, blank=True)
```

`forms.py` file:

```
from .models import Product
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class ProductCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Product
         fields = "__all__"
         labels = {
              "name": _("Product Name"), 
              "price": _("Price"), 
              "image": _("Image"),
         }
         required = (
              'name',
              'price',
              'image',
         )
```

Then within your view in the `views.py` file:

```
if request.method == "POST":
     form = ProductCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

     if form.is_valid():
          form.save()  # This here will save the necessary data to the database
     else:
          print(form.errors)  # To show you what field(s) are causing the form not to submit

     return redirect('shelf')
```

Finally, the `action` attribute is not needed on your `form` `tag`, so you can remove it since the same `function` will be handling the `post request`.

Additionally, ensure that in your `setting.py` file you have something set for the `MEDIA_URL` and the `MEDIA_ROOT`

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

In your project's `urls.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
     ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Will there still be need of specifying MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py

Comment: Yes, I've added that to the answer as a suggestion just in case you didn't have it. By having that the `upload_to='image_uploads/'` on the model will create a folder there called `image_uploads` then save the files in that newly created folder.

Comment: Ok, that will lead to putting   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)  in my urls.py

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: All done!. How then can I display it in the html file using the <img> tag

Comment: You would simply reference the file on the object by `<img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="..."/>`. Assuming that you have a `for loop` in your template: `{% for product in products %} <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="..."/> {% endfor %}`.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, probably should accept it as the answer to your post that it might help others with the same issue you had. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245702/discussion-between-joseph-morakinyo-and-damoiskii).

Answer (score 0):

Images are not saved in the database. they save in some storage and the path is stored in the database. I see you have not set any path to your imagefield , there should be something called the upload_to parameter.

something like this:

```
from django import form

class ProductCreationForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Product Name", max_length=250, required=True)
    price = forms.DecimalField(label="Price", required=True, initial=0)
    image = forms.ImageField(upload_to="projectimg/",label="Image", required=True, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': "image/x-png, image/jpeg"}))
```

Comment: is there a particular path am to set for the images or it auto creates a new path

Comment: Usually, the path you define  + the file name. Of course, you can modify both based on your need.